# Preventing gnuplot from evaluating function for each data point

Tags: gnuplot

I have trouble with some gnuplot `plot` command that is taking very long to execute. Basically, when you do the following with a data file:

```
f(x) = sin(x) # for example!
plot "data" u ($1-f($1)):2
```

`f($1)` will be evaluated for each data point that is to be plotted. Now, I have an *external* function:

```
a(i) = real(system(sprintf("awk 'NR==1 {print $6}' dos_%i", i)))
```

where the different `dos_1`, `dos_2`, etc. are my data files. This function returns a real number that is read from each file.

The problem is that when this function is used in a `plot` command, say

```
plot "dos_1" u ($1+a(1)):2
```

the function `a(1)` will be evaluated for each data point, even though it does not change. This can take *a lot* of time, because it is a function invoking an external command. Now, someone might (rightfully) suggest that if a(1) doesn't change I use a constant:

```
a1 = a(1)
plot "dos_1" u ($1+a1):2
```

which will execute considerably faster and give the same results. My problem is that I have to plot many files:

```
plot for [i=1:agazillion] "dos_".i u ($1+a(i)):2
```

which never ends.

How do I automatize the storage (and usage) of a function's value onto a static variable (or lighter function), schematically like this:

```
for [i=1:agazillion] "a".i = a(i) # This doesn't work!!!
plot for [i=1:agazillion] "dos_".i u ($1+"a".i):2 # This doesn't work either!
```

To complicate things, the latest gnuplot I have access to is 4.4. (Please also suggest solutions that work for later versions but *state* they only work for later versions).

Ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only "structure" I know would be using a word list to store the values. The iteration over the files must be done with bash, because version 4.4 can only loop inside a plot call, but not with `do for ...`:

```
a_values = system("for file in dos_*; do awk -v ORS=' ' 'NR==1 {print $6}' $file; done")

plot for [i=1:words(a_values)] "dos_".i u ($1+word(a_values, i)):2
```

I tested this to work with 4.4.4.

Comment: Nice, thanks. You can always rely on Christoph for gnuplot stuff :-)