# Gnuplot loop fitting, stats and plotting

Tags: for-loop, gnuplot

I'm having a hard time getting my `gnuplot` script to work. Basically, I have six data files and I want to plot them in the same file with a fit for every data set.

It gets a little complicated because I have to reformat the data before plotting. For that I am using `stats` commands. Here lies the problem. The final plotting command contains a `for` loop in which the data formatting is done. Each `stats` command produces statistical data with a prefix `Potentiali`, where `i` goes from 1 to 6.

Now my question is, how can I access this running index in the plot loop?

This is my script:

```
#!/bin/bash

gnuplot << EOF

set terminal epslatex color size 16cm,11cm
set output "strain-energy.tex"

set xrange [-10:10]
set yrange [0:*]


fstr(N) = sprintf('f%d(x) = a%d*x**7 + b%d*x**6 + c%d*x**5 + d%d*x**4 + e%d*x**3 + f%d*x**2 + g%d*x + h%d', N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N)
eval(fstr(1))

fitstr(N) = sprintf('set fit quiet; fit [-10:10] f%d(x) ''/path/Shift_%d/potential.dat'' every ::1 using (\$1-Potential%d_pos_min_y):(\$2-Potential%d_min_y) via a%d,b%d,c%d,d%d,e%d,f%d,g%d,h%d', N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N, N)

do for [i=1:6] {
    stats "/path/Shift_".i."/potential.dat" every ::1 using (\$1):(\$2) prefix "Potential".i nooutput
    eval(fstr(i))
    eval(fitstr(i))
}

plot for [i=1:6] "/path/Shift_".i."/potential.dat" every ::1 using (100*((\$1-Potential.i._pos_min_y)/Potential_pos_min_y)):(1000*(\$2-Potential_min_y)) ls i title "\\\footnotesize{C".i."}", f1(x) ls 1, f2(x) ls 2, f3(x) ls 3, f4(x) ls 4, f5(x) ls 5, f6(x) ls 6

set output
EOF
```

Comment: I'd really appreciate it, if somebody had the time to look into this, as I'm currently approaching a deadline.

Comment: It would be helpful if you removed the unnecessary code and focus on the problem, so any user willing to help doesn't get discouraged. This is a somehow related question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23671742/preventing-gnuplot-from-evaluating-function-for-each-data-point), you can store your values in a list and then access the elements using the `word()` function.

Comment: I know, I usually don't post questions of this quality but I'm really in a hurry. I cleaned up my script a little. Hope that helps.

Comment: If you are really in a hurry, my advice is to just serialize your script. Instead of doing things in a `for` loop, copy and paste the relevant `stats` line six times and change what you need to, then `plot '/path/Shift_1/potential.dat' ... `. Keeping the loops would likely require fiddling either with `word()` as @Miguel mentioned, or `eval` which will lead you down a dark and twisted road...

Comment: That should be easy. Thought about that in the beginning, but haven't considered it since running into these problems. It makes for an ugly script but I think I'm past caring.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In newer gnuplot versions use the `do for` construction to create a string with all the values you need and then use the `word()` function to select the one you want. If your variables are `a1`, `a2` and `a3` (change to the name in your particular case) then do:

```
a1=1.1; a2=2.2; a3=3.3 # Values
a="" # a is the string where all the values are stored
do for [i=1:3] {eval "a = sprintf(\"%s %g\", a, a".i.")"} # Print a1, etc. to a
print a # Just check what a looks like
  1.1 2.2 3.3
a(i) = real(word(a,i)) # Create function that depends on i
print a(1) # Check that a(1) indeed gives a1
 1.1
```

You'll need to adapt the above code to your purposes.